# Passport serialize is working but deserialize is not executing after deployed to ubuntu (nginx) servers it work fine in localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I have implemented passport google Oauth2.0 in the backend which works fine in localhost but when I deployed in Linux ubuntu server it failed to execute deserialize function in the passport

This is my main file

```
import express from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import path from "path";
import connectDB from "./Database/connectDB.js";
import cors from "cors";
import session from "express-session";
import passport from "passport";
import { Strategy as GoogleStrategy } from "passport-google-oauth20";
import { Strategy as FacebookStrategy } from "passport-facebook";
import googleAuthRoutes from "./Routes/googleAuthRoute.js";
import facebookAuthRoutes from "./Routes/facebookAuthRoute.js";
import UserModel from "./Models/UserModel.js";
import SpeakeroreCategoryRoute from "./Routes/speakeroreCategoryRoute.js";
import SpeakeroreEventRoute from "./Routes/speakeroreEventRoute.js";
import SpeakerorePaymentRoute from "./Routes/speakerorePaymentRoute.js";
import UserRoute from "./Routes/speakeroreUserRoute.js";
import CouponRoute from "./Routes/speakeroreCouponRoute.js";

// configure for dotenv file
dotenv.config({ path: path.resolve("./config.env") });

const app = express();

// function to make connection to database
connectDB()
  .then((res) => {
    console.log("connection to database is successful");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

// middlewares for app
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "https://example.com",
    credentials: true,
  })
);
app.set("trust proxy", 1);

// configuring session middleware
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSIONSECRET,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
      sameSite: "none",
      secure: true, // Set to true if using HTTPS
      maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // Session expiration time (in milliseconds)
    },
  })
);

// Initialize Passport.js
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Configure Passport.js session serialization
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.email);
});

passport.deserializeUser(async (email, done) => {
  try {
    // Find the user based on their ID
    const user = await UserModel.findOne({ email: email });

    if (user) {
      console.log("if is running", user);
      return done(null, user);
    } else {
      console.log("else is running");
      return done(null, false);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return done(error);
  }
});

// Configure Passport.js to use Google Strategy
passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.GOOGLECLIENTID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLESECRET,
      callbackURL: "/api/auth/google/callback", // Update with your callback URL
    },
    async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      try {
        const existingUser = await UserModel.findOne({
          email: profile._json.email,
        });

        if (existingUser) {
          // If the user already exists, return the user profile
          return done(null, existingUser);
        } else {
          const defaultAdmin = "ankitfukte11@gmail.com";
          let defaultUser;

          const responseData = profile._json;

          if (responseData.email === defaultAdmin) {
            let uniqueFirstChar;
            let uniqueSecChar;
            let uniqueNumber = responseData.sub.substring(
              responseData.sub.length - 4
            );

            if (responseData.given_name) {
              uniqueFirstChar = responseData.given_name.charAt(0);
            }
            if (responseData.family_name) {
              uniqueSecChar = responseData.family_name.charAt(0);
            }

            defaultUser = {
              alphaUnqiueId: `${uniqueFirstChar}${uniqueSecChar}${uniqueNumber}`,
              first_name: responseData.given_name,
              last_name: responseData.family_name,
              email: responseData.email,
              picture: responseData.picture,
              googleOrFacebookId: responseData.sub,
              role: "admin",
            };
          } else {
            let uniqueFirstChar;
            let uniqueSecChar;
            let uniqueNumber = responseData.sub.substring(
              responseData.sub.length - 4
            );

            if (responseData.given_name) {
              uniqueFirstChar = responseData.given_name.charAt(0);
            }
            if (responseData.family_name) {
              uniqueSecChar = responseData.family_name.charAt(0);
            }

            defaultUser = {
              alphaUnqiueId: `${uniqueFirstChar}${uniqueSecChar}${uniqueNumber}`,
              first_name: responseData.given_name,
              last_name: responseData.family_name,
              email: responseData.email,
              picture: responseData.picture,
              googleOrFacebookId: responseData.sub,
            };
          }

          const newUser = new UserModel(defaultUser);

          // Save the new user to the database
          const savedUser = await newUser.save();

          // Return the new user profile
          return done(null, savedUser);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        return done(error);
      }
    }
  )
);

// Configure Passport.js to use Facebook Strategy
passport.use(
  new FacebookStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.FACEBOOKAPPID,
      clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOKAPPSECRET,
      callbackURL: "/api/auth/facebook/callback",
      profileFields: ["id", "displayName", "email", "name", "profileUrl"],
    },
    async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      try {
        const existingUser = await UserModel.findOne({
          email: profile._json.email,
        });

        if (existingUser) {
          // If the user already exists, return the user profile
          return done(null, existingUser);
        } else {
          const defaultAdmin = "ankitfukte11@gmail.com";
          let defaultUser;

          const responseData = profile._json;

          if (responseData.email === defaultAdmin) {
            let uniqueFirstChar;
            let uniqueSecChar;
            let uniqueNumber = responseData.id.substring(
              responseData.id.length - 4
            );

            if (responseData.first_name) {
              uniqueFirstChar = responseData.first_name.charAt(0);
            }
            if (responseData.last_name) {
              uniqueSecChar = responseData.last_name.charAt(0);
            }

            defaultUser = {
              alphaUnqiueId: `${uniqueFirstChar}${uniqueSecChar}${uniqueNumber}`,
              first_name: responseData.first_name,
              last_name: responseData.last_name,
              email: responseData.email,
              picture: profile.profileUrl,
              googleOrFacebookId: responseData.id,
              role: "admin",
            };
          } else {
            let uniqueFirstChar;
            let uniqueSecChar;
            let uniqueNumber = responseData.id.substring(
              responseData.id.length - 4
            );

            if (responseData.first_name) {
              uniqueFirstChar = responseData.first_name.charAt(0);
            }
            if (responseData.last_name) {
              uniqueSecChar = responseData.last_name.charAt(0);
            }

            defaultUser = {
              alphaUnqiueId: `${uniqueFirstChar}${uniqueSecChar}${uniqueNumber}`,
              first_name: responseData.first_name,
              last_name: responseData.last_name,
              email: responseData.email,
              picture: profile.profileUrl,
              googleOrFacebookId: responseData.id,
            };
          }

          const newUser = new UserModel(defaultUser);

          // Save the new user to the database
          const savedUser = await newUser.save();

          // Return the new user profile
          return done(null, savedUser);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        return done(error);
      }
    }
  )
);

// Routes
app.use("/api/auth/google", googleAuthRoutes);
app.use("/api/auth/facebook", facebookAuthRoutes);
app.use("/api/categories", SpeakeroreCategoryRoute);
app.use("/api/events", SpeakeroreEventRoute);
app.use("/api/payments", SpeakerorePaymentRoute);
app.use("/api/users", UserRoute);
app.use("/api/coupons", CouponRoute);

// Start the server
app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${process.env.PORT}`);
});
```

This is my google auth controller;

I am expecting deserializeUser to execute on ubuntu servers. its like app running on localhost execute deserialize function but in production when i deployed it on server it skip deserializeUser function only serializeUser works